# Setar schema em consulta com Repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Tenho meu Repository:

```
  public class RepositoryBase<T> where T : class
  {
    protected AppDbContext _context;
    protected IDbSet<T> _dbSet;

    public RepositoryBase()
    {
      _context = _context ?? new AppDbContext();
      _dbSet = _dbSet ?? _context.Set<T>();
    }
    public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
      return _dbSet;
    }
  }
```

Nele tenho meu método GelAll.

Por padrão, o `Entity Framework` deixa o `Schema` DBO, correto?

Mas eu preciso fazer essa consulta em outro `Schema`,o qual seto em `Runtime`

Como poderia setar o `Schema` para esse `DbSet`?

Answer (score 1):

@Rod eu definiria esse schema no mapeamento de minha entidade. Que poderia ser passado como parâmetro ao `Context`.
Faria algo do tipo

```
public class MeuContext : DbContext
{
    string _schema = "";
    public MeuContext(string schema = "dbo")
    {
        _schema = schema;
    }
    public DbSet<Estado> Estado { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Estado>().ToTable("Estado", _schema);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Estado>().HasKey(a => a.EstadoId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Estado>().Property(a => a.EstadoId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

public class Estado
{
    public int EstadoId { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public string Tipo { get; set; }
}
```

Não cheguei a testar, mas acho que deve funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Pra redefinir em Runtime, você irá precisar de uma biblioteca que faça essa troca pra você:

> http://efmodeladapter.codeplex.com/

Se precisar que eu empacote a biblioteca em um pacote NuGet, só falar.

Ou você pode definir um método de extensão para `EntityConnection` com o seguinte:

```
public static EntityConnection Create(
    string schema, string connString, string model)
{
    XmlReader[] conceptualReader = new XmlReader[]
    {
        XmlReader.Create(
            Assembly
                .GetExecutingAssembly()
                .GetManifestResourceStream(model + ".csdl")
        )
    };
    XmlReader[] mappingReader = new XmlReader[]
    {
        XmlReader.Create(
            Assembly
                .GetExecutingAssembly()
                .GetManifestResourceStream(model + ".msl")
        )
    };

    var storageReader = XmlReader.Create(
        Assembly
            .GetExecutingAssembly()
            .GetManifestResourceStream(model + ".ssdl")
    );
    XNamespace storageNS = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl";

    var storageXml = XElement.Load(storageReader);

    foreach (var entitySet in storageXml.Descendants(storageNS + "EntitySet"))
    {   
        var schemaAttribute = entitySet.Attributes("Schema").FirstOrDefault();
        if (schemaAttribute != null)
        {
            schemaAttribute.SetValue(schema);
        }
    }
    storageXml.CreateReader();

    StoreItemCollection storageCollection =
        new StoreItemCollection(
            new XmlReader[] { storageXml.CreateReader() }
        );
    EdmItemCollection conceptualCollection = new EdmItemCollection(conceptualReader);
    StorageMappingItemCollection mappingCollection =
        new StorageMappingItemCollection(
            conceptualCollection, storageCollection, mappingReader
        );

    var workspace = new MetadataWorkspace();
    workspace.RegisterItemCollection(conceptualCollection);
    workspace.RegisterItemCollection(storageCollection);
    workspace.RegisterItemCollection(mappingCollection);

    var connectionData = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(connString);
    var connection = DbProviderFactories
        .GetFactory(connectionData.Provider)
        .CreateConnection();
    connection.ConnectionString = connectionData.ProviderConnectionString;

    return new EntityConnection(workspace, connection);
}
```

Ao instanciar o contexto, você passa pra ele a `EntityConnection` criada por este método.

Para mais dúvidas, [veja essa pergunta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663164/changing-schema-name-on-runtime-entity-framework).